# Misfire threshold in Quartz.Net

Tags: quartz.net

We are using quartz.net to schedule thousands of jobs. In case some of the jobs do not fire (due to non-availability of threads and misfire threshold setting), is there a way we can send a notification with the list of jobs that didn't fire?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that implements [ITriggerListener](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/ITriggerListener.cs) and the scheduler will notify you if any trigger misfires by calling the TriggerMisfired method.

Comment: Thanks! is there also a way to find out how long does a job take to complete execution? For ex. for each job, update the start time and completion time into DB. Can we write these inside the 'execute' method or is there any other way?

Comment: You can use a job listener (https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/IJobListener.cs). It will get called whenever the job starts and finishes. You'll have to save the start time to compute the duration but you can store it with the job data map itself so it's all self contained.